# TabLayout remove unnecessary scrolling

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I've encountered the tricky problem with android TabLayout

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
```

[image: To see what's going on, look at this gif]

When I select the foremost tab to the left, then scroll tabs to the right and select the foremost tab to the right, TabLayout first shows me the left tab again and then scrolls to selected tab to the right. Here's my setup code

```
    void setupTabs(ViewPager viewPager, TabLayout tabLayout) {
       ProductsPagerAdapter adapter = new ProductsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), rootCategory.getChildCategories());
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
       tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

       setStartingSelection(viewPager, adapter);


   }

    private void setStartingSelection(ViewPager viewPager, ProductsPagerAdapter adapter) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
            String title = (String) adapter.getPageTitle(i);
            if(title.equals(selectedCategory.getName())){
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back_white"
            app:title="@string/title_transport"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/title_color"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `AppBarLayout` should be a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` though! https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Comment: I tried to change it, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: If you comment in call of setStartingSelection method in setupTabs, does problem still persists?

Comment: Yes, setting starting section has nothing to do with how this widget scrolls when you select item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search I understood that I need another component which will look like TabLayout, but won't be TabLayout. So I used 
[ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator).

It is very similar to TabLayout, though it lacks cool selection animations and selected tab indicator animations, which are present in TabLayout. It also doesn't resize text to fit tabs, which is good, and it doesn't resize tabs to fit text either, which is bad (tried all style parameters that I know - could not make it wrap the text).

But it selects tabs just fine and without additional scrolling. AndroidArsenal unfortunately does not contain solutions, which are better than that (at least it didn't when I searched).

Answer (score 5):

you can try this code

```
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    // little hack to prevent unnecessary tab scrolling
    tabLayout.clearOnTabSelectedListeners();
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
    });
```

or you can also do this directly for the last line

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually you are dealing with Scrolling issue. Yes. the thing is, TabLayout Extends HorizontalScrollView.
try Something like this.

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {

public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

void init(Context ctx){

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Do not allow touch events.
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Do not allow touch events.
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: The thing is, if I do override these methods, them I will have to implement all select and scroll behaviour for myself. And providing that most of the TabLayout methods are private, this approach will have to use Reflection API too. But it is a possibility though.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth using [TabLayoutMediator](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator#tablayoutmediator_3)

and it will look like this

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabs, view_pager, true, false) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = ""
}.attach()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as below:

```
private void setStartingSelection(ViewPager viewPager, ProductsPagerAdapter adapter) {
        int tabPosition=0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
            String title = (String) adapter.getPageTitle(i);
            if(title.equals(selectedCategory.getName())){
                tabPosition=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabPosition);
    }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I am sorry, but I fear setting the starting selection does not help here. This scrolling appears not only the first time, but every time when you scroll tabs and select one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom ViewPager, may be it can help you :)

```
public class NonSmoothViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean mIsEnabledSwipe = true;

    public NonSmoothViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSmoothViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setEnabledSwipe(boolean isEnabledSwipe) {
        mIsEnabledSwipe = isEnabledSwipe;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return mIsEnabledSwipe && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return mIsEnabledSwipe && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap tablayout in horizontal scoll view like this

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/VW_C1">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/RankList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicator="@color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>
```